# CSS / google geochart stick tooltip to bottom of box

Tags: css, google-visualization, absolute

I am using Google Geochart to generate a map (works fine) but the client wants the tooltip to stick to the bottom of the wrapping div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/95f5A/)

Hover over the dark grey areas and a tooltip will appear in the bottom left below the map, but if you switch to another country e.g. canada and america, the tooltip will move slightly.

CSS:

```
.google-visualization-tooltip{
   position:fixed !important;
   bottom:10000px !important;
   left:0 !important;
   margin:500px 0 0 0 !important;
  }
```

Is there a way to do what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS to fix the position from the top of the page, not the bottom:

```
.google-visualization-tooltip{
    position: fixed !important;
    top: 0 !important;
    left: 0 !important;
    margin: 500px 0 0 0 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/95f5A/1/